# JQuery: Hide anchor if href is empty

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

Been on this one for a while now. Basically, I need to check where a `href` on an anchor tag with the class `.pdf-download` is empty, and if it is, hide it.

I have attempted a few options but with no luck. This is what i have so far:

```
$("a.pdf-download").each(function (i) {
  if ($('[href]:empty',this).length == 1) { 
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Guy - I see you have asked three questions and received some good answers. Make sure you mark an answer as correct by ticking the checkmark next to the best answer. It is how the SO community works. You may also want to read the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if ($(this).attr('href') != '') { 
    $(this).hide();
} else {
    $(this).show();
}
```

Note that you can also do this in css with [attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
a.pdf-download[href='']{
    display:none;
}
```

This is not supported in ie6 though.

Comment: +1 - I like the CSS solution. You can use that same selector in jQuery if you want too. `$('a[href=""]').hide();`

Comment: Note that that jQuery selector won't hide a link tag with no href attribute at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this with a jQuery selector, as follows:

```
// Hide any links with blank href or no href attribute
$('a.pdf-download[href=], a.pdf-download:not([href])').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this solution. it will also produce the desired results when the `href` attribute is not defined. If you use a CSS selector (JQuery), non-existent `href` attributes will not be detected.

```
$("a.pdf-download").each(function (i) {
    if (!this.href) { 
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
})
```

It's not necessary to use a JQuery method to get the `href` attribute, because`this.href` is just as readable, faster and also universally supported.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work?

```
$("a.pdf-download").each(function (i) {
  if ($(this).attr('href').length == 0) { 
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: This works if href is set on the element, but if it isn't it will throw an error. If you try `$('<a>test</a>').attr('href').length` it will return "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" as `.attr('href')` returns `undefined`. I imagine in most cases this method will work fine, but it's worth noting this caveat.

Answer (score 1):

I am a jquery beginner myself, but thats how I would do it:

```
$("a.pdf-download").each(function (i) {

    var aHref = $(this).attr('href');

    if (aHref == '' || !aHref) {

        $(this).hide();

    };

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BZq9c/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    $('a').each(function() {
        (!$(this).attr('href')) ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
    });

});
```

Almighty Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/each/j9DGw/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.pdf-download").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href == '') {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

or

```
$("a.pdf-download[href='']").remove()
```